# Add class to table in render array

Tags: 7, theming

I am looking to add a class to a table that I am creating.

I have the code:

```
$build['table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
);
```

I want to add a class to this table.  I don't have any templates for the view of this table, so I don't really want to have to create a tpl.php for it, but I will if I have too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is description of all parameters that you can pass to theme_table() function [http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7)

To add classes for table tag use this code:

```
$build['table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#attributes' => array (
    'class' => array('class name goes here'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: You're my knight in shining armour.